# grub-mkconfig Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution

Tags: 17.04

I tried to use the command `sudo update-grub`, but the response was:

```
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 36: /etc/default/grub: Syntax error: EOF in backquote substitution
```

Then when I open `/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig`, this is what is inside:

```
#! /bin/sh
set -e

# Generate grub.cfg by inspecting /boot contents.
# Copyright (C) 2006,2007,2008,2009,2010 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
#
# GRUB is free software: you can redistribute it and/or modify
# it under the terms of the GNU General Public License as published by
# the Free Software Foundation, either version 3 of the License, or
# (at your option) any later version.
#
# GRUB is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
# but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
# MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the
# GNU General Public License for more details.
#
# You should have received a copy of the GNU General Public License
# along with GRUB.  If not, see <http://www.gnu.org/licenses/>.

prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="/usr"
datarootdir="/usr/share"

prefix="/usr"
exec_prefix="/usr"
sbindir="${exec_prefix}/sbin"
bindir="${exec_prefix}/bin"
sysconfdir="/etc"
PACKAGE_NAME=GRUB
PACKAGE_VERSION=2.02~beta3-4ubuntu2.2
host_os=linux-gnu
datadir="${datarootdir}"
if [ "x$pkgdatadir" = x ]; then
    pkgdatadir="${datadir}/grub"
fi
# export it for scripts
export pkgdatadir

grub_cfg=""
grub_mkconfig_dir="${sysconfdir}"/grub.d

self=`basename $0`

grub_probe="${sbindir}/grub-probe"
grub_file="${bindir}/grub-file"
grub_editenv="${bindir}/grub-editenv"
grub_script_check="${bindir}/grub-script-check"

export TEXTDOMAIN=grub
export TEXTDOMAINDIR="${datarootdir}/locale"

. "${pkgdatadir}/grub-mkconfig_lib"

# Usage: usage
# Print the usage.
usage () {
    gettext_printf "Usage: %s [OPTION]\n" "$self"
    gettext "Generate a grub config file"; echo
    echo
    print_option_help "-o, --output=$(gettext FILE)" "$(gettext "output generated config to FILE [default=stdout]")"
    print_option_help "-h, --help" "$(gettext "print this message and exit")"
    print_option_help "-v, --version" "$(gettext "print the version information and exit")"
    echo
    gettext "Report bugs to <bug-grub@gnu.org>."; echo
}

argument () {
  opt=$1
  shift

  if test $# -eq 0; then
      gettext_printf "%s: option requires an argument -- \`%s'\n" "$self" "$opt" 1>&2
      exit 1
  fi
  echo $1
}

# Check the arguments.
while test $# -gt 0
do
    option=$1
    shift

    case "$option" in
    -h | --help)
    usage
    exit 0 ;;
    -V | --version)
    echo "$self (${PACKAGE_NAME}) ${PACKAGE_VERSION}"
    exit 0 ;;
    -o | --output)
    grub_cfg=`argument $option "$@"`; shift;;
    --output=*)
    grub_cfg=`echo "$option" | sed 's/--output=//'`
    ;;
    -*)
    gettext_printf "Unrecognized option \`%s'\n" "$option" 1>&2
    usage
    exit 1
    ;;
    # Explicitly ignore non-option arguments, for compatibility.
    esac
done

if fgrep -qs '${GRUB_PREFIX}/video.lst' "${grub_mkconfig_dir}/00_header"; then
  echo "GRUB >= 2.00 has been unpacked but not yet configured." >&2
  echo "grub-mkconfig will not work until the upgrade is complete." >&2
  echo "It should run later as part of configuring the new GRUB packages." >&2
  exit 0
fi

if [ "x$EUID" = "x" ] ; then
  EUID=`id -u`
fi

if [ "$EUID" != 0 ] ; then
  root=f
  case "`uname 2>/dev/null`" in
    CYGWIN*)
      # Cygwin: Assume root if member of admin group
      for g in `id -G 2>/dev/null` ; do
    case $g in
      0|544) root=t ;;
    esac
      done ;;
  esac
  if [ $root != t ] ; then
    gettext_printf "%s: You must run this as root\n" "$self" >&2
    exit 1
  fi
fi

set $grub_probe dummy
if test -f "$1"; then
    :
else
    gettext_printf "%s: Not found.\n" "$1" 1>&2
    exit 1
fi

# Device containing our userland.  Typically used for root= parameter.
GRUB_DEVICE="`${grub_probe} --target=device /`"
GRUB_DEVICE_UUID="`${grub_probe} --device ${GRUB_DEVICE} --target=fs_uuid 2> /dev/null`" || true

# Device containing our /boot partition.  Usually the same as GRUB_DEVICE.
GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT="`${grub_probe} --target=device /boot`"
GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT_UUID="`${grub_probe} --device ${GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT} --target=fs_uuid 2> /dev/null`" || true

# Filesystem for the device containing our userland.  Used for stuff like
# choosing Hurd filesystem module.
GRUB_FS="`${grub_probe} --device ${GRUB_DEVICE} --target=fs 2> /dev/null || echo unknown`"

if [ x"$GRUB_FS" = xunknown ]; then
    GRUB_FS="$(stat -f --printf=%T / || echo unknown)"
fi

if test -f ${sysconfdir}/default/grub ; then
  . ${sysconfdir}/default/grub
fi
for x in ${sysconfdir}/default/grub.d/*.cfg ; do
  if [ -e "${x}" ]; then
    . "${x}"
  fi
done

# XXX: should this be deprecated at some point?
if [ "x${GRUB_TERMINAL}" != "x" ] ; then
  GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT="${GRUB_TERMINAL}"
  GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT="${GRUB_TERMINAL}"
fi

termoutdefault=0
if [ "x${GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT}" = "x" ]; then
    GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT=gfxterm;
    termoutdefault=1;
fi

for x in ${GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT}; do
    case "x${x}" in
    xgfxterm) ;;
    xconsole | xserial | xofconsole | xvga_text)
            # make sure all our children behave in conformance with ascii..
        export LANG=C;;
    *) echo "Invalid output terminal \"${GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT}\"" >&2 ; exit 1 ;;
    esac
done

GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT="$GRUB_DEFAULT"

if [ "x${GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT}" = "xsaved" ] ; then GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT="`"${grub_editenv}" - list | sed -n '/^saved_entry=/ s,^saved_entry=,,p'`" ; fi

if [ "x${GRUB_RECOVERY_TITLE}" = "x" ]; then
  GRUB_RECOVERY_TITLE="recovery mode"
fi


# These are defined in this script, export them here so that user can
# override them.
export GRUB_DEVICE \
  GRUB_DEVICE_UUID \
  GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT \
  GRUB_DEVICE_BOOT_UUID \
  GRUB_FS \
  GRUB_FONT \
  GRUB_PRELOAD_MODULES \
  GRUB_ACTUAL_DEFAULT

# These are optional, user-defined variables.
export GRUB_DEFAULT \
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT \
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET \
  GRUB_TIMEOUT \
  GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE \
  GRUB_DEFAULT_BUTTON \
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_BUTTON \
  GRUB_TIMEOUT_BUTTON \
  GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE_BUTTON \
  GRUB_BUTTON_CMOS_ADDRESS \
  GRUB_BUTTON_CMOS_CLEAN \
  GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_XEN_DEFAULT \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_XEN_REPLACE \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_XEN_REPLACE_DEFAULT \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_NETBSD \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_NETBSD_DEFAULT \
  GRUB_CMDLINE_GNUMACH \
  GRUB_TERMINAL_INPUT \
  GRUB_TERMINAL_OUTPUT \
  GRUB_SERIAL_COMMAND \
  GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID \
  GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY \
  GRUB_VIDEO_BACKEND \
  GRUB_GFXMODE \
  GRUB_BACKGROUND \
  GRUB_THEME \
  GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX \
  GRUB_DISABLE_OS_PROBER \
  GRUB_INIT_TUNE \
  GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT \
  GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK \
  GRUB_BADRAM \
  GRUB_OS_PROBER_SKIP_LIST \
  GRUB_DISABLE_SUBMENU \
  GRUB_RECORDFAIL_TIMEOUT \
  GRUB_RECOVERY_TITLE \
  GRUB_FORCE_PARTUUID \
  GRUB_DISABLE_INITRD

if test "x${grub_cfg}" != "x"; then
  rm -f "${grub_cfg}.new"
  oldumask=$(umask); umask 077
  exec > "${grub_cfg}.new"
  umask $oldumask
fi
gettext "Generating grub configuration file ..." >&2
echo >&2

cat << EOF
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by $self using templates
# from ${grub_mkconfig_dir} and settings from ${sysconfdir}/default/grub
#
EOF


for i in "${grub_mkconfig_dir}"/* ; do
  case "$i" in
    # emacsen backup files. FIXME: support other editors
    *~) ;;
    # emacsen autosave files. FIXME: support other editors
    */\#*\#) ;;
    *)
      if grub_file_is_not_garbage "$i" && test -x "$i" ; then
        echo
        echo "### BEGIN $i ###"
        "$i"
        echo "### END $i ###"
      fi
    ;;
  esac
done

if [ "x${grub_cfg}" != "x" ] && ! grep "^password" ${grub_cfg}.new >/dev/null; then
  chmod 444 ${grub_cfg}.new || true
fi

if test "x${grub_cfg}" != "x" ; then
  if ! ${grub_script_check} ${grub_cfg}.new; then
    # TRANSLATORS: %s is replaced by filename
    gettext_printf "Syntax errors are detected in generated GRUB config file.
Ensure that there are no errors in /etc/default/grub
and /etc/grub.d/* files or please file a bug report with
%s file attached." "${grub_cfg}.new" >&2
    echo >&2
  else
    # none of the children aborted with error, install the new grub.cfg
    mv -f ${grub_cfg}.new ${grub_cfg}
  fi
fi

gettext "done" >&2
echo >&2
```

I think my `grub-mkconfig` is wrong, I can't identify where the problem is specifically. It might be that my `grub-mkconfig` is in the default settings.